# How to remove first array name from json

Tags: php, json

I'm Getting values like this in JSON format -

```
   {
        "comments": [{
            "name": "ABC",
            "desc": "Hello...",
            "values": [{
                "status": "fine",
                "label": ""
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "XYZ",
            "desc": "Good Morning..",
            "values": [{
                "status": "fine",
                "label": "happy"
            }]
        }]
    }
```

But i don't want first array name means i need result like this -

```
[{
   "name": "ABC",
     "desc": "Hello...",
     "values": [{
         "status": "fine",
         "label": ""
      }]
  }, {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "desc": "Good Morning..",
     "values": [{
          "status": "fine",
          "label": "happy"
      }]
 }]
```

Need a help...

Comment: Basically asking for the job to be done for him.

Comment: the reason of down vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this...

```
<?php
$json='{
        "comments": [{
            "name": "ABC",
            "desc": "Hello...",
            "values": [{
                "status": "fine",
                "label": ""
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "XYZ",
            "desc": "Good Morning..",
            "values": [{
                "status": "fine",
                "label": "happy"
            }]
        }]
    }';

    $arr=json_decode($json,1);
    echo json_encode($arr['comments']);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[{"name":"ABC","desc":"Hello...","values":[{"status":"fine","label":""}]},{"name":"XYZ","desc":"Good Morning..","values":[{"status":"fine","label":"happy"}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

---

```
$data = '[{
   "name": "ABC",
     "desc": "Hello...",
     "values": [{
         "status": "fine",
         "label": ""
      }]
  }, {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "desc": "Good Morning..",
     "values": [{
          "status": "fine",
          "label": "happy"
      }]
 }]';
$return = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($return as $key => $value){        
    unset($return[$key]['name']);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($return);
echo '</pre>';
```